# How does Apple Pay work

Tags: apple-pay

Can someone give me an overview as to how Apple Pay works. What goes on inside it. What microchips are used and essentially how does it work?

Comment: Apple Pay is not a chip, it is a payment processing service. It uses NFC (near field communication) to communicate with payment terminals at retailers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best write-up I know of. In typical Ars Technica fashion, it tells you everything you could ever want to know. A must-read for the curious: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/10/how-mobile-payments-really-work/

Answer (score 0):

This is a helpful description [macworld article on Apple Pay in the UK](http://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/apple/complete-guide-apple-pay-faqs-when-will-apple-pay-launch-in-uk-release-date-3544309/%23uklaunch)